# Retorno de consulta MySQL com PHP+JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdo

Estou criando uma consulta em PHP em um banco MySQL. Até ai tudo bem. A consulta funciona direitinho. Estou chamando a consulta a partir de um javascript usando `$.post('pagina.php',meusparametros,function(resultado){})` para inserir o resultado da pesquisa na minha página html. Até consigo ver o resultado aparecer no html quando faço o teste. O problema é que na seqüência parece que a página dá um "refresh"... aí some tudo. =(

Porém, se eu "printo" o while por exemplo em um alert que seja, ele me mostra o resultado da pesquisa...

arquivo.js

```
$(function(){    
    $("#btnPesquisa").click(function(){
        var usr = $("#idUsr").val();
        var dti = $("#dtinicio").val();
        var dtf = $("#dtfinal").val();
        if(usr != ""){
            var sDados = {
                usuario : usr,
                dtinicio : dti,
                dtfinal : dtf
            }
            $.post('pesquisa.php',sDados,function(retorno){
                $(".resultado").html(retorno);
            });
        }else{
            $(".resultado").html('');
        }
    });
});
```

pesquisa.php

```
require "conexao.php";
require "Usuario.class.php";
try{
    $usr = $_POST['usuario'];
    $dti = $_POST['dtinicio'];
    $dtf = $_POST['dtfinal'];
    $u = new Usuario();
    $sDados = $u->pesquisaAcessos($usr,$dti,$dtf);
    while($result=$sDados->fetch()){
        echo '<li>'.$result['ocorrencia'].'</li>';
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo '<script text="text/javascript"> alert("'.$e->getmessage().'")</script>';
}
```

pagina.html

```
    <article class="cam-article">    
        <form class="menu-form" name="pesquisa" id="pesquisa" action="" method="POST">
            <div class="menu-card">
                <div class="menu-div-bar card-group">
                    <input type="text" id="idUsr" name="usuario" placeholder="Digite o nome do usuário">
                </div>
                <div class="menu-div-bar card-group">
                    <input type="date" id="dtinicio" name="dtinicio">
                </div>
                <div class="menu-div-bar card-group">
                    <input type="date" id="dtfinal" name="dtfinal">
                </div>
                <div class="menu-div-bar card-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="menu-btn" name="btnPesquisa" id="btnPesquisa">PESQUISAR</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <article class="cam-article">
            <ul class="resultado">
            </ul>
        </article>
    </article>
```

Comment: Mostre o código do btnPesquisa, provavelmente ele está enviando o form.

Comment: Desculpe-me, editei lá a pergunta, não sei se é assim que faz, sou novo aqui no fórum... tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o que está acontecendo com o seu código é que você está dando um submit no seu formulário, por padrão o submit faz um redirect para o caminho que está apontado na `action` do seu formulário. E como a `action` do seu formulário está vazio por padrão ele redireciona para a própria página. Você resolver isso de duas formas:

Modificar o type do `<button>`

De:

```
<button type="submit" class="menu-btn" name="btnPesquisa" id="btnPesquisa">PESQUISAR</button>
```

Para:

```
<button type="button" class="menu-btn" name="btnPesquisa" id="btnPesquisa">PESQUISAR</button>
```

ou você pode adiconar o comando `event.preventDefault()` na função JS:

```
$("#btnPesquisa").click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var usr = $("#idUsr").val();
    var dti = $("#dtinicio").val();
    var dtf = $("#dtfinal").val();
    if(usr != ""){
        var sDados = {
            usuario : usr,
            dtinicio : dti,
            dtfinal : dtf
        }
        $.post('pesquisa.php',sDados,function(retorno){
            $(".resultado").html(retorno);
        });
    }else{
        $(".resultado").html('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Fabio, obrigado pela ajuda! Alterando o type <button> resolveu mesmo! Obrigado, entretanto  o event.preventDefault(); não surtiu efeito. Obrigado mesmo pela ajuda"

Answer (score 1):

Quando você clica no botão "submit" ele envia o form, então após exectar a função onClick a página é recarregada, uma solução é o `preventDefault()` seu código js seria:

```
$("#btnPesquisa").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // função que impede o envio do form,  evento padrão
    var usr = $("#idUsr").val();
    var dti = $("#dtinicio").val();
    var dtf = $("#dtfinal").val();
    if(usr != ""){
        var sDados = {
            usuario : usr,
            dtinicio : dti,
            dtfinal : dtf
        }
        $.post('pesquisa.php',sDados,function(retorno){
            $(".resultado").html(retorno);
        });
    }else{
        $(".resultado").html('');
    }
});
```

Outra forma seria simplesmente apagar a tag form do html.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que ao dar click no botão, além da chamada do `$.post` também é feito o submit do form. No caso como o action é nulo, parece 'sumir tudo'.

Existem 3 formas de resolver isso:

1. Retirar o `type='submit'` do botão e retirar o form.
2. Inserir `event.preventDefault();` no javascript como outras respostas citaram.
3. Setar o action do form para `pesquisa.php` e manter o `type='submit'` do botão. Aí não precisa mais de javascript. Os dados já são enviados direto pro php. Mas aí o pesquisa.php precisa retornar uma página HTML válida e não só os resultados.

**Edit**

Para a oção 3 apenas mude o PHP para:

```
require "conexao.php";
require "Usuario.class.php";
try{
    $usr = $_POST['usuario'];
    $dti = $_POST['dtinicio'];
    $dtf = $_POST['dtfinal'];
    $sDados = $u->pesquisaAcessos($usr,$dti,$dtf);
    echo "<html><body><ul>";
    while($result=$sDados->fetch()){
        echo '<li>'.$result['ocorrencia'].'</li>';
    }
    echo "</ul></body></html>";
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo '<script text="text/javascript"> alert("'.$e->getmessage().'")</script>';
}
```

e remova todo o javascript

Comment: Nelson, muito obrigado! pela ajuda, vou pesquisar mais sobre a opção 3 da sua resposta. Se você puder exemplificar, fico grato! Obrigado pelas dicas!